# Swapped keys with French macintosh keyboard in ElementaryOs

Tags: keyboard, macintosh

I'm using a French Macintosh keyboard with Loki and for some reasons the keys highlighted in the picture are swapped. How do I swap them back?  Is it possible to manually change the keyboard layout?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use an app called KeyMapper to modify my keys.  In my case, I'm using it to make Mac's COMMAND -> CONTROL and the native PC keyboard ALT -> CONTROL.

https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper

Answer (score 0):

Go to System settings -> keyboard. There you can add other keyboard Layouts. 
(+)Icon -> choose French -> choose the layout that fits your keyboard (there is one called Macintosh, maybe this fits, if not try the others)

Afterwards you can delete your first layout.

Comment: The _French (Macintosh)_ layout in this menu has the `@/#` key at the bottom left of the keyboard, and `</>` at the top left. The _real_ Macintosh layout has these two keys swapped, exactly like in OP's picture. So this layout is not correct regarding these keys.